# Order/sort a structure section by date too?

Tags: structure, sections, ordering

Is it possible to have a Structure section ordered by date (desc) as a default and then take the custom ordering in the CP into account?

Answer (score 5):

This should work

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'news',
    sortOrder: 'postDate desc, lft asc',
}) %}
```